# Outlook VBA automatically sending delivery receipt

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

Whenever I invoke the following vba code to automatically send an email, outlook automatically sends a delivery receipt. I have displayed the email before sending and can confirm that the "Request Delivery Receipt" is not selected. Even then when I send the email it will still send a delivery receipt. This does not happen for emails I normally (i.e. not automated) send through the same inbox.

```
Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set mailItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With mailItem
    .To = "person@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "This is the subject"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "This is the body"
    .OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = False
    .ReadReceiptRequested = False
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: So it turns out this only happened when I was sending to myself. Didn't happen for other email addresses. Go figure.

Comment: Do these properties get reset to `true` for the message in the Sent Items folder? You can check in OutlookSpy (I am its author) - select the message, click Item button.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any other peroperties or methods for that. So, your code is valid.

Be aware, other software or COM add-ins that handle the `ItemSend` event of the `Application` class could impact or change the mentioned in the code properties by setting them to `true` instead.